# Get byte array for ZipArchive in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-ziparchive

I'm trying to write code to remove the `_MAXOSX` folder from a zip archive if it exists (breaks validation further down the line if it exists).

The code must return a `byte[]` and not the ZipArchive itself.  The code I currently have is:

```
var fileBytes = uploadController.FileBytes;
if (stripMacOSXFolder && uploadController.FileName.EndsWith(".zip", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    try
    {
        using (var data = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(data, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            var osx = archive.Entries.SingleOrDefault(c =>
                c.FullName.Equals("__MACOSX/", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (osx != null)
            {
                osx.Delete();
                // SET fileBytes to archive byte[]
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return new ObjectReturnMethodResult<UploadedFileV2>("Uploaded zip appears to be invalid.");
    }
}
```

It's not clear to me once I've deleted the entry how I set `fileBytes` to the byte array of the updated ZipArchive.

Comment: Ata guess: `fileBytes = data.ToArray();` I'm assuming it updates the stream.

Comment: @Llama unfortunately after `osx.Delete();` if I add `fileBytes = data.ToArray();` it doesn't appear to work - the folder is not removed from the archive.

Comment: Did you do that after `ZipArchive` had been disposed of? If you did it inside then perhaps it hadn't written the changes.

Comment: Ah, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchivemode?view=net-5.0#remarks) seem to support that theory: _"When you set the mode to Update, the underlying file or stream must support reading, writing, and seeking. The content of the entire archive is held in memory, and **no data is written to the underlying file or stream until the archive is disposed**."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs for `Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchivemode?view=net-5.0#remarks) mode state:

> When you set the mode to Update, the underlying file or stream must support reading, writing, and seeking. **The content of the entire archive is held in memory, and no data is written to the underlying file or stream until the archive is disposed.**

It seems that you will need to obtain the updates bytes after the `ZipArchive` has been disposed of:

```cs
using (var data = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(data, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        var osx = archive.Entries.SingleOrDefault(c =>
            c.FullName.Equals("__MACOSX/", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (osx != null)
        {
            osx.Delete();
        }
    }
    fileBytes = data.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: ZipArchive is a weird beasty! I've been caught by not Disposing before.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, one mistake I made in my code is that the delete entry method deletes the root folder entry but not the sub entries, so you have to loop each on deleting also which is also a little non obvious :P